# How to send files from client to http node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http, post

I am trying to send a file from a javascript file (client) to a node server. The server is receiving the request but when I console.log(request.body) it returns undefined. I have no idea why the file is not attached to the request.body when I post it to the server. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

client.js (javascript that runs in browser)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

const request = require('request')


class App extends Component {

  onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
    request.post('http://localhost:8088', {
      file: acceptedFiles[0]
    }, (error, res, body) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return
      }
      console.log(`statusCode: ${request.statusCode}`);
      console.log(body);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop}>
        {({getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive}) => (
          <div {...getRootProps()}>
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
            {isDragActive ? "Upload file" : 'Click me or drag a file to upload!'}
          </div>
        )}
      </Dropzone>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

server.js (node server)

```
const http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 8088;

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    console.log(request.body);
    if (request.method == 'POST') {
      console.log('POST');
    }
    else {
      console.log('GET');
      response.statusCode = 200;
      response.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
      response.end('Node server');
    }
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: @Alphastrick — `request` is a wrapper around it

Comment: You'll need to use something like `FormData` and `multer` to send files to node.

Comment: There is no such thing as [`request.file`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage). If you invent properties, it is very likely that they don't exist

Comment: I keep getting this error in the console ```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8088/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.```

Comment: you have to allow cors from your server

Comment: thanks for the reply vipin. I got it to work a while :) if you post that as a answer I will mark this it as the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use Filepond JavaScript file upload library. Check out it's docs at  https://github.com/pqina/filepond

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to send data from client to server. I have used fetch as it is inbuilt in javascript so there is no need of any third-party module to make ajax call

```
 onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
  fetch('http://localhost:8088', {
      method: "POST",
      body: this.getFormData({
          file:acceptedFiles[0]
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
       // you will get response here 
 });
}
```

```
getFormData(object = {}) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value]) =>
      formData.append(key, value)
    );
    return formData;
}
```